# Redmine rest api returns html document

Tags: rest, redmine, redmine-api

I try connect pycharm/small python projects to my redmine server, but rest api return this:

```html
Error fetching issues for: /projects//issues.xml?key=(my secret key)&fields%5B%5D=status_id&operators%5Bstatus_id%5D=o&values%5Bstatus_id%5D%5B%5D=1&per_page=10, HTTP status code: 200
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<meta name="VERSION" content="">
<meta name="DATA" content="fwdnode7-bl.web-hosting.com (my redmine server)">
<link href=" " rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
<title></title>
</head>
<frameset rows='100%, *' frameborder=no framespacing=0 border=0>
<frame src="http://(my redmine server)" name=mainwindow frameborder=no framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></frame>
</frameset>
<noframes><h2>Your browser does not support frames. We recommend upgrading your browser.</h2><br><br>
<center>Click <a href="http://(my redmine server)" >here</a> to enter the site.</center>
</noframes>
</html>
```

Information about environment:

```
  Redmine version                2.5.1.stable.13174
  Ruby version                   2.0.0-p481 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.18
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
```

REST API and JSON are enabled in redmine's setting

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there an error in your URL? It should contain a project id between '//': /projects//issues.xml

Comment: There is some component between your local puthon client and your Redmine server generating this frameset. Redmine itself doesn't use frames at all. Check with your web hoster what they have there and why it injects itself into your requests.